# Validar string em número com php

Tags: php

Eu me deparando com a seguinte situação. Tenho uma string e tenho que validar o seu valor. Dessa forma, tenho que verificar se é número inteiro. Então terei que passar a string para número e verificar se é inteiro ou float.

Pensei em algo assim:

```
if((int)"13.1" == 13.1){
   echo "certo";        
}
```

O problema, é se apessoa digital true ou false.

```
if((int)"true" == "true"){
    echo "certo";   
}
```

Ainda é possível, a pessoa passar valor não string. Como faço para validar, neste caso. Eu preciso que aceite apenas número inteiro, mas muitas das vezes eu irei receber este valor em string, e posso receber em boolean ou float...  Como validar nesta situação?

```
1    = true
1.1  = false
true = false
"ss" = false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função filter_input.
Segue um exemplo:

```
$peso = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'peso', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (!$peso) {
   echo 'Valor inválido.';
}
```

Mais exemplos aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php

(Edit)
Tem mais explicações legais de filtros também aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filter.asp

Comment: Isso aí vai dar problema se a pessoa passar a string `0`. Um teste correto seria `if( $peso === false )`

Comment: @Bacco Na realidade não apenas string, como também o número 0.

Comment: @abcd é que você mencionou que passa strings na pergunta, de fato no GET nunca vem como número, só por isso não entrei em detalhes. Mas o importante é que você entendeu a idéia ;)

Comment: Acabei utilizando o seguinte: `if(filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>0, "max_range"=>10))) === false) {echo "foi";}` . ATT

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar uma função de teste nativa do PHP

```html
<?php

$var1 = "0";

if (is_int($var1)) {
  echo "OK";
}

?>
```

Comment: Marcolla, essa função não serve, pois como dito acima, eu recebo string, daí teria que saber se float ou int.