# Verificar se o valor é inteiro

Tags: php

Galera uso o seguinte código em `php` para verificar se o número é inteiro:

```
$qtd_bo = "1.20";

if (!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $qtd_bo)) {
    echo "Não é inteiro";
}
```

Ele me retorna que o número 1.20 não é inteiro. Até ai ok.

O problema é que se eu coloco 1.00 ele me fala que não é inteiro.

Eu preciso verificar se existe algum valor após o "."

Comment: [Validar string em número com php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139898/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O valor `1.00` sempre vai ser considerado um `float`, porém você pode validá-lo da seguinte maneira:

```
$value = "1.00";
return floor($value) != $value;
```

Caso o valor em `float` realmente seja um "inteiro", a condição irá retornar `TRUE`, pois o `PHP` compara os valores sem levar em conta o tipo e a função [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) retorna justamente a parte inteira, apenas.

Comment: muito bom, o meu código ficou assim : `if (floor($value) != $value) {
    echo "Não é inteiro";
}`

Comment: Perfeito, simples né...

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser fazer com `regex`:

```
<?php

    $testes = array('-65','065','16as321','132,16','16544.01','-1');

    foreach ( $testes as $valor ){
        printf( "%s %s um número inteiro\n" , $valor , preg_match( '/^\-?[1-9][0-9]*$/' , $valor ) ? 'é' : 'não é' );
    }

?>
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/w5TupM).

No `PHP`, existe o [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-int.php), que informa se a variável é do tipo inteiro.

```
<?php
   if (is_int(23)) {
      echo "is integer\n";
   } else {
      echo "is not an integer\n";
   }
   var_dump(is_int(23));
   var_dump(is_int("23"));
   var_dump(is_int(23.5));
   var_dump(is_int(true));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

O número 1 é `int` mas 1.0 não é `int`, é um `float` ou também pode ser `double` ou `decimal` dependendo da linguagem. Entendeu a diferença?

Portanto 1.0 ou 1.0000, nunca será um `int`.

Comprove com um teste

```
$str = 1.00;
var_dump(gettype($str)); // retorna double
var_dump(is_int($str)); // retorna false
```

Um adendo, tome cuidado com essa expressão regular, pois -1 é um inteiro, mas a expressão retorna falso:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]*$/', $str)) {
    echo 'não é inteiro';
}
```

Testando número inteiro negativo

```
$str = -1;
var_dump(gettype($str)); // retorna integer
var_dump(is_int($str)); // retorna true
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php